# Why questions related to ubuntu-one client for windows and osx are ontopic here?

Tags: discussion

Why questions related to ubuntu-one for windows and osx are ontopic here?

Is it an exception? If no why questions related to firefox(It is also part of ubuntu) for windows are offtopic here?

**Edit1**

Questions related to ubuntu-one for windows and mac are very rare here.So it is not a big issue for us but I am asking about our policy

Comment: Ubuntu One  is maintained by Canonical, unlike Firefox. Since Ubuntu  One is a service provided by Canonical (Ubuntu) it's on-topic here.

Comment: @Marco Ceppi: means questions about every canonical products are ontopic? Including unity shell in fedora? :)

Comment: Does Canonical support unity in fedora? As far as I know it was experimental. And Ubuntu-One is officially supported for the other OS's like windows and OSX

Comment: @MarcoCeppi: You really should have posted that as an answer :P

Comment: yeah only @MarcoCeppi can answer this question clearly ;-)

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Jorge already gave a good answer, I was just addressing the why not X question

Comment: @Marco Ceppi : still waiting for an awesome answer from you :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this issue can no longer be reproduced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is because FAQ says

**We welcome questions about:**

- Using and administering Ubuntu, including official Ubuntu derivatives.
- Running third-party applications on Ubuntu.
- Development on Ubuntu.
- Services provided by Ubuntu

Ubuntu one is a service provided by Ubuntu so it is on topic

---

I personally disagree with this , because    **Services provided by Ubuntu** is too vague . ubuntu-one [websites](https://one.ubuntu.com/about/) says

> Ubuntu One was initially launched in May 2009 to provide sustainable
>   revenue for Ubuntu, the world’s most popular free operating system,
>   which is commercially backed by Canonical.

Ie, it is simply a project to earn money to support Ubuntu development. So can way say ubuntu one is a ubuntu project? My answer is *only the Ubuntu client for ubuntu-one is ubuntu service,rest of them are just canonical service*

**Use up/down vote and comment to this opinion :-)**

Answer (score 5):

This site is "Ask Ubuntu", it just so happens that some Ubuntu things can run on other OSes. :)

The Ubuntu One team monitors [ubuntu-one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-one), so it probably makes more sense to have all those questions in one place, though it's not like we're flooded with OSX/Windows questions to begin with.

Comment: What about ubuntu-one on mint, just saw this and am not sure... http://askubuntu.com/questions/215941/ubuntu-one-on-linux-mint-wont-install-depends-libnautilus-extension1a

Comment: The only supported platforms for U1 are Windows/OSX/Ubuntu afaict.

Comment: My doubt is whether ubuntu-one is canonical thing or ubuntu thing :)