# What is the "Ubuntu" referring to in "Ask Ubuntu"?

Tags: discussion

*This question is based on [this answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/5365/39372).*

I thought here we use "Ubuntu" to mean the Ubuntu operating system only, so the [following quote](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/5365/39372) from Jorge Castro confused me:

> This site is "Ask Ubuntu", it just so happens that some Ubuntu things
>   can run on other OSes. :)

Does that mean here "Ubuntu" refers to all Ubuntu products?

If so, then **How can I define "Ubuntu" in the Ask Ubuntu [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq)?**

[The FAQ says](https://askubuntu.com/faq):

> Ask Ubuntu is a questions and answers site for Ubuntu-related
>   questions. It's also a place to share knowledge about Ubuntu.

*Sorry for my bad English, I don't know how to phrase my question. :(*

Answer (score 2):

Yes Ubuntu as in Ubuntu the operating system, there are some things that break the standard...

[Ubuntu-One](https://one.ubuntu.com/about/):

> Ubuntu One is the personal cloud that brings your digital life
>   together, so you can enjoy your content, your way, wherever you are.
>   With our suite of cloud services including storage, sync, sharing and
>   streaming - you have immediate access to your music collection,
>   favorite photos, videos, important documents and more, at any time and
>   from any device.

And It runs on windows and mac, that is what [Jorge Castro](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/235/jorge-castro) is talking about.

And in the FAQ it says

> We welcome questions about:
>
> Using and administering Ubuntu, including official Ubuntu derivatives.
>      Running third-party applications on Ubuntu.
>      Development on Ubuntu.
>      Services provided by Ubuntu

Some of the "Services" (like ubuntu-one) provided by Ubuntu also run on mac and windows.

Comment: This is an answer  for my previous question, I think you posted it here by mistake :)

Comment: Were you not confused about Jorge Castro's Answer?